# Endpoint Load balancing and Fail-over simultaneous configuration wso2apim

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, high-availability

I have 3 endpoints in my wso2apim publisher. I want to have load-balance configuration between 1 and 2 and Failover configuration for 1 and 3 (1 is main endpoint). I am able to add either Failover or Load Balance but not both at a time in endpoint configuration. Just wanted to know if this is possible to achieve in wso2apim 3.2.0

If I add fail over configuration -> load balance configuration gets reset
If I add load balance configuration -> fail over configuration gets reset

[image: FailOver configuration][image: Load Balance configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are defining the loadbalance endpoints you can enable failover and specify endpoints as failover endpoints. So only when the primary Endpoint fails the failover endpoint will trigger.

[image]

**Update:** It seems this is not available in version 3.2.0. One workaround would be to manually enable failover configs. When you create an Endpoint the relevant configurations are added to wso2am-3.2.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/endpoints

You may be able to add the failover configs directly to this file. This is because the underline runtime does support failover. You can refer to [1] for more info.
The downside is if you republish the API through the publisher,the Endpoint configurations will reset. You can get around this by changing the default templates located at wso2am-3.2.0/repository/resources/api_templates. You can refer to [2] for more details on this.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Load-balance+Group+

[2] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/customizing-api-template-for-gateway/#engaging-a-custom-handler-based-on-api-properties